#  How to include a PSTricks animation into a beamer?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, animate

I'm trying to create an animation to include into a beamer. I figured (naively I suppose) a way to do that is to create a Pdf with animate package, and then  `\includegraphics` it into my beamer. Running on Mac Os X 10.5.8 with Texlive.

Here is what I'd like to animate :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{animate} 
\newcommand{\rotatingarrow}[1]{

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(10,10)% 

\psaxes(0,0)(9,9)
\rput(6,1){\Huge{Temps = #1 s}}
\rput{#1}(4,4){

\psline[linecolor=blue,arrowsize=5pt]{->}(0,0)(2,1)\rput{#1}(2.3,1.3){\Huge{$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{v}}$}}
\psline[linecolor=red,arrowsize=5pt]{->}(2,1)(1,3)\rput{#1}(1.3,3.3){\Huge{$\textcolor{red}{\vec{a}}$}}
}

\end{pspicture}% 
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{animateinline}[poster=last,loop,autoplay,width=5cm,height=5cm]{12}% 
\multiframe{36}{iAngle=0+10}{% 

\rotatingarrow{\iAngle}% 
}% 
\end{animateinline}% 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Then compiling with LaTeX.

When I open it with Adobe, it does what I want. However, the animation isn't cropped. Then, pdfcrop seems to kill the file. After running pdfcrop on it, it'll be simply blank.

My question is : How do I proceed to have a cropped animation like I see in every tutorial ? How to include that animation into a Beamer (I suppose my idea is wrong).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### What makes a PDF with working animations no longer work?

There are 3 cases that will make working animations in a PDF file *NO* longer work. For simplicity, let `animation.pdf` be the PDF file with working animations.

1. We compress `animation.pdf` with  `gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=animation-compressed.pdf animation.pdf`.
2. We crop  `animation.pdf` with `pdfcrop animation.pdf animation-cropped.pdf`.
3. We import `animation.pdf` from within a LaTeX input file by using `\includegraphics{animation.pdf}`.

### `\animateinline` versus `\animategraphics`

Recall  that *we cannot embed a PDF with animation into another document* as what [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) said, we have two options to solve your problem. Just choose one of the following.

1. Use `animateinline` environment to sandwich your animation codes, and put the environment into your host input file (which is an input file with `beamer` document class in your case). However this approach has 3 drawbacks: (a) you cannot use `pdflatex` to compile your host input file when the animation codes in PSTricks language. (b) your host input file contains both text and codes so it become long, crowded, hard-to-understand, difficult to maintain, etc, (c) compilation will take longer time because the animation codes get recompiled whenever you make any changes. That is why I suggest you to do the second option below.
2. Use `\animategraphics` instead of `animateinline`. `\animategraphics` allows you to import any PDF with one or more pages to be animated.

The theory is enough. Now the following will explain the second option (using `\animategraphics`). There are 2 steps as follows:

### Solution

1. In my opinion, it will be better if you cut the animation code from the host input file (presentation with beamer in your case ) and paste the animation code into a single, *TeXable* input file. TeX the animation input file to produce a PDF output. Later, you can make use of this PDF to create many other projects such as GIF animation, PDF animation (in your case), PNG images, etc. This separation method also make your host input file neater, cleaner, readable, understandable, etc.

   Let `Simple.tex` be the TeXable animation input file as follows:

   ```
   %Simple.tex  using standalone document class

   \documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pstricks-add}

   \newcommand\RotatingArrow[1]{%
       \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,11)
           \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.3](-1,-1)(10,11)
           \psset{arrows=->}
           \psaxes(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9,10)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
           \rput(4.5,0.6){\Huge{Temps = #1 s}}
           \rput{#1}(4.5,5.5){%
               \psset{arrowsize=5pt}
               \pnode(2,0){A}
               \pnode(2,3){B}
               \psline[linecolor=blue](A)
               \uput[0]{-#1}(A){\Huge{$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{a}}$}}
               \psline[linecolor=red](A)(B)
               \uput[90]{-#1}(B){\Huge{$\textcolor{red}{\vec{v}}$}}
           }
   \end{pspicture}} 

   \begin{document} 
       \multido{\i=0+10}{36}{\RotatingArrow{\i}}
   \end{document}
   ```

   For those who are unlucky to use `standalone` document class, the last resort is to use `preview` as follows. Note that `standalone` also uses `preview` internally.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pstricks-add}


   \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
   \PreviewBorder=0pt
   \PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


   \newcommand\RotatingArrow[1]{%
       \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,11)
           \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.3](-1,-1)(10,11)
           \psset{arrows=->}
           \psaxes(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9,10)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
           \rput(4.5,0.6){\Huge{Temps = #1 s}}
           \rput{#1}(4.5,5.5){%
               \psset{arrowsize=5pt}
               \pnode(2,0){A}
               \pnode(2,3){B}
               \psline[linecolor=blue](A)
               \uput[0]{-#1}(A){\Huge{$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{a}}$}}
               \psline[linecolor=red](A)(B)
               \uput[90]{-#1}(B){\Huge{$\textcolor{red}{\vec{v}}$}}}
   \end{pspicture}}

   \begin{document}
       \multido{\i=0+10}{36}{\RotatingArrow{\i}}
   \end{document}
   ```

   TeX it with either `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` to get a PDF file. In our example, it will contain 36 pages to create a simple animation as follows.

   [image]
2. Now, you create the beamer as follows.

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{animate}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}{Circular motion in action}
   \animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=0.5]{10}{Simple}{}{} % WARNING: the filename must not include its extension!
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   TeX it with either `pdflatex` (recommended) or `xelatex`. [And the following image shows your presentation with a *working* animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcAUd.gif)

### The latest edit

We can also combine both input files into single input file as follows. Compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%====================== BEGIN FILE CONTENTS ==========================
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\newcommand\RotatingArrow[1]{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.3](-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psset{arrows=->}
        \psaxes(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9,10)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \rput(4.5,0.6){\Huge{Temps = #1 s}}
        \rput{#1}(4.5,5.5){%
            \psset{arrowsize=5pt}
            \pnode(2,0){A}
            \pnode(2,3){B}
            \psline[linecolor=blue](A)
            \uput[0]{-#1}(A){\Huge{$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{a}}$}}
            \psline[linecolor=red](A)(B)
            \uput[90]{-#1}(B){\Huge{$\textcolor{red}{\vec{v}}$}}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=0+10}{36}{\RotatingArrow{\i}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%====================== END FILE CONTENTS =========================

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{latex dummy}
\immediate\write18{dvips dummy}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps}
\begin{frame}{Circular motion in action}
    \animategraphics[controls,scale=0.5]{10}{dummy}{}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As for 1(b), you could also improve readability of the host document source by moving the `animateinline` code into an external file and `\input{...}` it where needed.

Comment: But that is problem 1(a) ;)

Comment: As for compilation time, there is still the `draft` option available for intermediate compilations.

Comment: I did click the arrow, but don't have sufficient reputation to upvote. 

Seems I spoke too fast about it working beautifully.

If I compile Simple.tex with Xelatex, it will spit out 36 images beside one another, and not 36 different pages.I tried putting a \newpage at the end of the newcommand, but it will just do the same (1 page) vertically.

When compiling it gives me a warning : 
LaTeX Warning : Unused global option(s): [pstricks].

Comment: For the sources, I use the two you've written above.

Compiling with either Xelatex, or latex dvips ps2pdf, the ouput will be a horizontal picture assembled of 36 pictures.

I've found a way around it, but it is ugly.
I replaced the document class by article. Used the \package{auto-pst-pdf}. Then, the Simple-pics.pdf output has 36 different pages. Ultimately I used your beamer source to have the animation. It works, but is cumbersome.

Maybe I have some updates to do.

Comment: I tested your second code in which you avoid standalone : it works. I will probably have to upgrade my whole Tex release.
Thanks a lot for the effort in being so clear and patient.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The verbatim code in the animate documentation are minimal working examples that can be compiled as they are. You cannot embed a pdf with an animation into another document. Just insert the `\begin{animateinline}...\end{animateinline}` stuff into your `beamer` document source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Inserting the animate code directly into the beamer works fine. However, when doing that the following problem comes up :

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\texwidth}}
    Some text.... &
    \begin{animateinline}....\end{animateinline}
    \end{tabular}

The text will be below the bottom of the animation window, as opposed to simply next to it. What is the problem here ?

Comment: @Mathusalem: The animation box behaves exactly like an embedded graphics, that is, its base line is aligned with the base line of the surrounding text. Maybe the animation box is too large to fit into the table cell? Could you please edit your (compilable) example code above to show the problem?

Comment: Why does `\animategraphics` produce an error when the  file extension is explicitly specified?

Comment: @HiggsBoson In case of a numbered sequence, the file number would sit between the base name, shared by all files, and the extension. Maybe I'll add an option to enforce a specific file extension.