# PSTricks Animation and dvips

Tags: beamer, pstricks, animate, dvips, ps2pdf

I want to create animation in Beamer using the animate package.
I easily created a basic example following the "all-in-one approach" from this [older post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64834/how-to-include-a-pstricks-animation-into-a-beamer) but I can not use pdflatex to compile, which leads to my issue.

I use this minimal code (copied from mentioned post) in a file called main.tex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%====================== BEGIN FILE CONTENTS ==========================
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\newcommand\RotatingArrow[1]{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.3](-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psset{arrows=->}
        \psaxes(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9,10)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \rput(4.5,0.6){\Huge{Temps = #1 s}}
        \rput{#1}(4.5,5.5){%
            \psset{arrowsize=5pt}
            \pnode(2,0){A}
            \pnode(2,3){B}
            \psline[linecolor=blue](A)
            \uput[0]{-#1}(A){\Huge{$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{a}}$}}
            \psline[linecolor=red](A)(B)
            \uput[90]{-#1}(B){\Huge{$\textcolor{red}{\vec{v}}$}}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=0+10}{36}{\RotatingArrow{\i}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%====================== END FILE CONTENTS =========================

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{latex dummy}
\immediate\write18{dvips dummy}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps}
\begin{frame}{Circular motion in action}
    \animategraphics[controls,scale=0.5]{10}{dummy}{}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works fine when I compile in command line using:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
```

However, as because of other tricks I usually use in my presentations, I need to use the route latex->dvips->ps2pdf, but when I compile doing:

```
latex main.tex
dvips main.dvi
ps2pdf main.ps
```

I get the error:
**Package animate Error: Missing frame number in \animategraphics command.**
THis error occurs after the step: latex main.tex

According to the animate package [documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/animate/animate.pdf), I think it should work but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Though the documentation mentions 
some issue with this way of compiling, I do not manage to work through it.
Any pointer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\animateinline` instead. It makes life easier:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand\RotatingArrow[1]{%
    \psset{unit=0.5}\footnotesize
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psframe*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.3](-1,-1)(10,11)
        \psset{arrows=->}
        \psaxes(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9,10)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \rput(4.5,0.6){Temps = #1 s}
        \rput{#1}(4.5,5.5){%
            \psset{arrowsize=5pt}
            \pnode(2,0){A}
            \pnode(2,3){B}
            \psline[linecolor=blue](A)
            \uput[0]{-#1}(A){$\textcolor{blue}{\vec{a}}$}
            \psline[linecolor=red](A)(B)
            \uput[90]{-#1}(B){$\textcolor{red}{\vec{v}}$}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=last, controls, palindrome]{12}%
\multiframe{36}{iAngle=0+10}{\RotatingArrow{\iAngle}}%
\end{animateinline}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works a s a charm with latex->dvipsps->ps2pdf. I use it jointly with matlabfrag to get some simple animations out of Matlab.